# A team of 6 members is formed from 6 males and 8 females

Tags: probability

A team of 6 members is formed from 6 males and 8 females.

What is the probability that the team has equal numbers of male and female ?

I calculated 20/3003 = 0.0067 
Is it correct? 
Help me with this problem, please

Comment: Where did $20$ and $3003$ come from?

Comment: 20 is commutation of n = 14, r = 6 and 3003 is commutation of n = 6, r = 3

Comment: You forgot that the male committee members can be chosen in more than one way.

Comment: Oh, thank you ! So this is permutation then?

Comment: If I use permutation, then 120/40320 = 0.003 . Is it the correct answer?

Comment: No, it's not like that.  You had 3003 ways to pick 6 members out of 14, and 20 ways to pick 3 women out of 6.  Now you need to account for the different ways to pick 3 men out of 8.  Each choice of 3 men and 3 women gives you a valid committee.

Comment: Ooh, ok, thank you so much for your help and time !

Comment: So, the answer is 20/3003 + 56/3003 ?

Comment: No, each committee has both women and men.  You use the so-called "multiplication rule."  You'd use the "addition rule" if you were counting the different ways to pick either three women or three men.  But here you need to pick 6 members, not 3.  For every way to choose 3 women, there are 56 ways to choose 3 men and vice versa, for every way to choose 3 men, there are 20 ways to choose 3 women.

Comment: How many ways are there to form a committee of 6 choosing from 14?  You correctly counted 3003.  Now you need to count how many of those committees have 3 men and 3 women, and then take the ratio.

Comment: Thank YOU sooo much! You saved my day!  Good luck   to you

Answer (score 1):

You start with the equal number of male and female part in a team of 6 which gives you 3 male members and 3 female members. Now your job is to select 3 male team members from a group of 6 and 3 female members from a group of 8.

Number of ways to select male members = ${6}\choose 3$

Number of ways to select female members = ${8}\choose 3$

As they are independent events, we get the number of ways to form a team of equal male and female members by multiplying to get

$${{6}\choose{3}} {{8}\choose{3}}$$

And as we know total number of ways to select a team out of $8 + 6 = 14$ people is =  $14\choose6$

Dividing the two, we get the probability as

$$\frac{{{6}\choose{3}} {{8}\choose{3}}}{14\choose6} = \frac{1120}{3003} = 0.3729$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $6M$ and $8F$.
For equal number of $M$ and $F$ in a team, you need $3M$ and $3F$.
So, you require to select $3M$ from $6$ and $3F$ from $8$.

So, selection goes like: $$^6C_3\cdot ^8C_3$$
Whereas, total ways to select $6$ people from $14$ is $$^{14}C_6$$
So, required probability will be:$$\frac{^6C_3 \cdot ^8C_3}{^{14}C_6}$$